# Is there a way with spring data jdbc avoid n+1 issue?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jdbc

When I run this query, I experience n+1 issue where data JDBC fetches all the related entities of the campaign objects. Is there any way to avoid this using data JDBC?

```
@Query(
    """
  SELECT campaign.*
  FROM campaign
           JOIN targeting ON campaign.targeting_id = targeting.id
  WHERE (
    CASE
        WHEN campaign.applications_close_date IS NOT NULL
            THEN NOW() BETWEEN campaign.start_date AND campaign.applications_close_date
        WHEN campaign.end_date IS NOT NULL
            THEN NOW() BETWEEN campaign.start_date AND campaign.end_date
        ELSE NOW() >= campaign.start_date
        END
    )
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
     FROM application
     WHERE application.campaign = campaign.id
      AND application.influencer = :influencerId 
    )
  """
  )
  fun findAllMatchingByInfluencerId(
    influencerId: Long,
    country: String?
  ): List<Campaign>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

If you don't need the referenced entities you should use a class that doesn't have those properties as a return value.

If you actually want those referenced entities, but have a more efficient way to construct the entity with its references you may specify your own `ResultSetExtractor` or `RowMapper` in the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: I'm trying to use RowMapper and having the troubles with mapping one-to-many relationship. I can't inject the repository into my RowMapper to fetch all related entities by ID, console says:
Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No argument provided for a required parameter: parameter #0 repository of fun <init>(io.promoty.core.campaign.repository.Repository): io.promoty.core.campaign.rowMapper.RowMapper
How would you solve this issue?

Comment: This is a separate question, please create it as such, so others have a chance of finding it and the answer.